# How to set the environment variable CHROME_BIN when working in an IDE?

Tags: angularjs, environment-variables, karma-runner

I'm trying to follow the AngularJS tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial. I use the IDE Cloud9.

When I enter `npm test` it returns `No binary for Chrome browser on your platform. Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.` And the same message for `FIREFOX_BIN`.

How am I supposed to set these environment variables?

I've tried the following:

- In the command prompt of Windows (on my pc, not in cloud9) I entered `SET CHROME_BIN = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` but this didn't make a difference.
- I also tried it when changing `karma.conf.js` to:

  ```
  browsers : ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'],
  ```

  but then I got the error `Can not load "Script", it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?` so that doesn't seem to be the right way to go either.
- If in Cloud9 I enter `env SET CHROME_BIN = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` it returns `env: SET: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same problem using the Cloud9 IDE.

While, I didn't solve the Chrome problem, I went with PhantomJS, which worked with Cloud9.

To install on the command line:

```
npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
```

In the karma.conf.js file:

```
// start these browsers
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Add variable for the current user using powershell:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("CHROME_BIN",'...', "User")
```

This is not exactly the same as what you want as variable will not be temporary but the effect will be the same.

Your own command will work if you execute it in the same shell as npm:

```
   PS> $Env:CHROME_BIN = '...'
   PS> npm test
   ...
```

I am using here Powershell syntax exclusively.

I am not familiar with Cloud9 but generally, to set variable up for the IDE you would need to run it from the script that sets the variable prior to launching the IDE (the same as I showed you with nmp above).